# How can I use Maven fail safe plugin to execute the pre-integration steps

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

I need to execute a testNG (config) test before the regression suite. This test does some config related tasks and creates users. Can somebody please explain the following POM. I am still trying to understand how to define the step in the POM.xml. The name of my test is CreateUsers.xml. Where should I define this in the following POM.XML. I am using jenkins to run these tests. Please advice. Thanks

What does id, goal and include tags mean ?

```html
<build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/PreTest.class</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>int-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/IntTest.class</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have added my per-requisite testNG as below. Please advice if this is correct ? Thanks

```html
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.21.0</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
 
<executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>CreateUsers.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
 
</executions>
```

Comment: If you already use TestNG you can use things like ' @BeforeTest` or `@BeforeGroup` etc. could be used for such things..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I want to use it with jenkins. Jenkins should run this pre-integration test first and then the regression suite. I am not sure how to do this ?

Comment: Can somebody please advice ? I have been working on this for a while and couldn't resolve it.

Comment: @BobJones - Have you explored leveraging configuration annotations such as `@BeforeSuite` (executed only once per `<suite>`), `@BeforeTest` (executed only once per `<test>`), `@BeforeGroups` (executed once per groups), `@BeforeClass` executed only once before any `@Test` method is executed in a class or `@BeforeMethod` which gets called before every `@Test` method is executed. This would get executed all the time. Why wouldn't that work for you ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to run this pre-requisite test before every regression test. It will be difficult or combersome to pu testng annotations for every test. More so this pre-requisite test is from another class.

Comment: @BobJones - In that case, have you considered leveraging TestNG listeners ? They are completely separate from a test, and then can be plugged in and out at will. You should look at `org.testng.ITestListener` or `org.testng.ISuiteListener` for a start. Would that work ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan how can we use BeforeSuite from different class